# How to customize the font and margin for lstlistoflistings TOC entry?

Tags: listings, titletoc

In my LaTeX template, I define the chapter and section TOC entry with the `titletoc`
package:

```
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\vspace{.1\baselineskip}\bfseries}
    {\thecontentslabel\hspace{2.8mm}}{}
    {\hspace{.5em}\titlerule*[5pt]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}
```

But I don't know how to apply this to the `listing` environment.

I guess it would be:

```
\titlecontents{listing}[0pt]{\vspace{.1\baselineskip}\bfseries}
    {\thecontentslabel\hspace{2.8mm}}{}
    {\hspace{.5em}\titlerule*[5pt]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}
```

But I am wrong.  Does anyone know how to do that? I need to ensure that the TOC entry style is consistent.

Comment: There is no relation of `toc` and `listings` What do you want to achieve? Please provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Just use `\contentsuse{lstlisting}{lol}` and then `\titlecontents{lstlisting}...` should work.

Comment: There are also some other questions on this topic, e.g. [lstlistoflistings font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11637/), [Customizing the list of listings generated by \lstlistoflistings?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27645/). This question can be closed as a duplicate, but not as "too localized".